# Terrmcolor with Powershell don't show the results on color

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

i have a problem when i use the package termcolor with powershell

when i execute my code: there is no color for the word i put 
Ex :

```py
import pyfiglet
from termcolor import colored


msg = input('what do you want to print : ')

color = input('what color: ')

asc = pyfiglet.figlet_format(msg)
colored = colored(asc, color=color)
print(colored)
```

Comment: Where in your code is PowerShell involved?

Comment: Can you please update your question showing how PowerShell is used? We can't offer any help if we can't see any code :)